# Adding a variable to a meta field in the backend?

Tags: plugins, custom-field, automation

I have a plugin which lets me create retailers. These retailers all have a meta field called commission - the value of which I might need to change down the road. Most of them are just set to 15 at the moment, but if I had to change that to, say, 20, I would have to go into every retailer and change that information.

How do I create a variable instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a function and execute wp_query for retailer posttype and get all data of retailers and then using foreach loop of that retailers use this: update_post_meta($post_id, 'your_field_name', 'YOUR_NEW_VALUE');